# Does the length of a primary key affect query performance?

Tags: mysql

Does the character length of a primary key significantly affect query performance? For example, if the field were 128 characters vs. 64 characters?

Comment: Which data type?

Comment: varchar is the datatype

Comment: For VARCHAR and the same data there is usually no difference. The exception is when temporary tables with memory engine are used, because it only can use fixed length data types.

Comment: Would it be the same for CHAR(64) vs. CHAR(128)? Looking to make a primary key for SHA256 vs. SHA512 keys.

Comment: Well it depends. If you have many indexes on that table (any index will contain the primary key in InnoDB) and you have many foreign keys referencing that column, the performance impact might become significant. But in that case I woul consider to use an integer type (AUTO_INCREMENT) as primary key.

Comment: Premature optimisation is the root of all evil.

Comment: @eggyal Database design is not premature. It's not that easy to change it later.

Comment: No. Not much. But why not test it. (And it's 'love of premature optimisation ...')